# JAX WS сервис на Spring Boot

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, jax-ws

Кто может объяснить подробнее алгоритм решения задачи?

> Написать приложение на SpringBoot, которое предоставляет JAXWS сервис
>   к таблице БД. В качестве БД использовать h2 in memory database. 
>   Таблица Sample в БД должна содержать несколько колонок разных типов
>   (строка,число,дата).

JAXWS сервис содержит 1 метод get на получение всех строк таблицы. 
Честно скажу, это задание на собес, уже вторую неделю пытаюсь разобраться, в интернете на такую связку максимум 2 статьи на английском и то там слишком мудрено. Проблема заключается в том, что реализовать подобный функционал на спринг бут у меня получилось, а вот куда и как тут засунуть еще JAX WS у меня под большим вопросом. 
Мавен сборка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestTask-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TestTask-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main бут класс

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestTask1Application {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hello there!";
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestTask1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Сущности

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Sample")
public class CivilWars {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long Id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;

    private Date DATEBEGIN;

    private Date DATEEND;

    private long victims;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Date getDateBegining() {
        return DATEBEGIN;
    }

    public void setDateBegin(Date DATEBEGIN) {
        this.DATEBEGIN = DATEBEGIN;
    } 

    public Date getDateEnd() {
        return DATEEND;
    }

    public void setDateEnd(Date DATEEND) {
        this.DATEEND = DATEEND;
    } 

    public long getVictims() {
        return victims;
    }

    public void setVictims(long victims) {
        this.victims = victims;
    }
}
```

И соответственно контроллер

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/show")
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    TestTaskRepository testTaskRepository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<CivilWars> getAll() {
        return testTaskRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Код заполнения БД опустил, в итоге после запуска приложения если перейти по ссылке http://localhost:8080/show через запятую в фигурных скобках будут представлены все сущности. Получается как бы задание выполнено, но вот JAX WS то каким боком? Скорее всего я чего то не догоняю в архитектуре построения веб приложений. Кто может простым языком объяснить как решить задачу согласно требованию, что почитать, чтоб не заблудиться в океане информации?

Comment: Может в квадратных скобках? Что за собес?

Comment: JAX-WS это XML, а ты JSON возврашаешь, это к слову

Comment: Есть же пример https://github.com/alexleigh/spring-boot-jaxws-demo

Comment: Что непонятного? http://herrho.com/jax-ws-webservice-with-spring-boot-and-jax-ws-ri/

Comment: Это как раз те 2 примера) второй проект я уже импортировал через гит, он оказался нерабочим

Comment: А первый пример?